# In Emacs Lisp, how do I check if a variable is defined?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In Emacs Lisp, how do I check if a variable is defined?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

you may want boundp: returns t if variable (a symbol) is not void; more precisely, if its current binding is not void. It returns nil otherwise.

examples from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html#index-boundp) (assuming dynamic binding):

```
  (boundp 'abracadabra)          ; Starts out void.
  => nil

  (let ((abracadabra 5))         ; Locally bind it.
    (boundp 'abracadabra))
  => t

  (boundp 'abracadabra)          ; Still globally void.
  => nil

  (setq abracadabra 5)           ; Make it globally nonvoid.
  => 5

  (boundp 'abracadabra)
  => t
```

Comment: sometimes it might also be useful to use INTERN-SOFT to check whether a symbol exists.

Comment: I also sometimes use `symbol-value` function to print the actual value. [symbol-value-doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Variables.html#Accessing-Variables). Egs: Using the `eval-expression` command and then typing this out:  `(symbol-value 'abracadabra)`

Comment: The `let` block returns `nil` for me. Does this work with lexical binding?

Comment: HappyFace: No, *lexical* variables are not associated with the global symbol of the same name.  You would need to `(defvar abracadabra)` in that file to ensure it was a dynamic variable.  (But when it comes to `boundp` specifically, the nature of lexical scope is also such that it wouldn't really make sense to attempt to check whether a lexical variable was bound, because the answer is never in question.)

Answer (score 53):

In addition to [dfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757564/in-emacs-lisp-how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-defined/757593#757593) you may also want to see if it's bound as a function using [fboundp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html):

```
(defun baz ()
  )
=> baz
(boundp 'baz)
=> nil
(fboundp 'baz)
=> t
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check a variable value from within emacs (I don't know if this applies, since you wrote "in Emacs Lisp"?):

`M-:` starts `Eval` in the mini buffer. Write in the name of the variable and press return. The mini-buffer shows the value of the variable.

If the variable is not defined, you get a debugger error.

Comment: Equivalently, `M-: (boundp 'the-variable-name) RET` will check without the need for triggering an error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is about elisp scripts, not the interactive UI of Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that variables having the value nil is regarded as being defined.

```
(progn (setq filename3 nil) (boundp 'filename3)) ;; returns t

(progn (setq filename3 nil) (boundp 'filename5)) ;; returns nil
```